# Iterate over Google Sheet range with 3 columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import certain data points from one Google sheet to another. I have successfully targeted the data and created 3 variables to hold them.

The final step (i.e. where I get stuck) is to create new rows with 3 columns to store them.

It keeps throwing out: "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid."

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i ++) {
var name = data[i][1];
var hour = data[i][9];
var money = hour * 40;

var range = sheet.getRange(i, 0, 1, 3);
values = [[name, hour, money]];
range.setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices needed for getRange are one based.
Try

```
var range = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3);
```